# Getting the name of a submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 on the .Net platform and have the following html in my view. As you can see the names are the same to distinguish which button is pressed when going into the Controller to take the proper action.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="btnRefresh" value='Refresh' />
    </td>
        @if (Model.ShowGeneratePDFBtn == true)
        {
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="btnGeneratePDF" value='Generate PDF' />
            </td>
        }
</tr>
```

However, when the second ("Generate PDF") button is pressed, I need to disable it so the user won't be able to press it again while a process is taking place. If I disable it, it no longer appears in the html as a control (which is understandable).

Here is the js:

```
$('#btnGeneratePDF').click(function () {
    DisableGeneratePDF();
});

function DisableGeneratePDF() {
    $('#btnGeneratePDF').attr("disabled", true);
}
```

In the Controller, the value of the button when pressed is null instead of "Generate PDF", so the proper action doesn't get executed.

Here is the first line in the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessForm(string submitbutton, ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors model, FormCollection collection)
```

Here is the first line in the View. I also tried it with FormMethod.Post, but since I'm not going to another page the AjaxOption would be more efficient.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessForm", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
```

**How can I successfully pass the "Generate PDF" value to the Controller when I disable the button?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden form value and put this in your view model. Then set that value in you click event handler.

To your model, add the following

```
public class Guarantors
{
    public bool ShouldGeneratePdf { get; set; }
}
```

To your view, add

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ShouldGeneratePdf)
```

To your JavaScript

```
$('#btnGeneratePDF').click(function () {
    DisableGeneratePDF();
    $('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val('True');
});

function DisableGeneratePDF() {        
    $('#btnGeneratePDF').attr("disabled", true);
}
```

That ought to do it.

Comment: Better write `$('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(true)`

Comment: Simon, I tried your solution, but didn't work... Here is the code I added: js: $('#btnGeneratePDF').click(function () {
        DisableGeneratePDF();
        $('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(true)
    });

    function DisableGeneratePDF() {
        $('#btnGeneratePDF').attr("disabled", true);
    }

Comment: View: @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ShouldGeneratePdf) I also added this to my exisitng ViewModel that I am using for the View:   public bool ShouldGeneratePdf { get; set; } The value still comes out null.

Comment: Any advice on what I might be missing?

Comment: I can tell you that it seems like @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ShouldGeneratePdf) doesn't contain a value...

Comment: I know the js executes to set this as I saw while debugging: $('#ShouldGeneratePdf').val(true)

Comment: Jarrett, I got it thanks to you.... I was checking the value of the "submitbutton" variable in the Controller instead of the value in the model, which is now set to true and can execute the correct method. Thanks so much for showing me this technique.

Comment: Jarrett, when I run my website locally or even when I run it locally pointing to my staging server, it works just fine as I explained. However, if I try and run it from the actual staging server, when clicking the "Generate PDF" button, doesn't kick off the process. It's as if the value is coming back false and not executing the part I need to be executed. I triple verfified that the js is NOT commented out. It disables the button, but no activity. Is there anything I need to do implement on the staging server? Is there anything I can do implement or anything I can do to narrow it down?